# Placing national flags at start of sentence

Tags: html

I need to display a string in two languages: English and Dutch.

It would be nice to show an English flag at the start of the English sentence, and a Dutch flag at the start of the Dutch sentence. For example:

[image: Eglish flag]    `This is an English text.`

[image]   `Dit is een Nederlandse text.`

What I currently use is an Image. But I was wondering if there are other ways to do it. For example through HTML Entities? Or maybe something else?

Comment: There aren't entities or Unicode characters for flags.

Comment: As Alex mentioned below, use images, but still applying them using CSS. See here how this can be nicely solved: https://www.flag-sprites.com/en_US/ - You can apply a style sheet etc. "flag flag-cz" and loading a sprite is good too (might be not though, if you just want to have 2 languages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML, CSS or Unicode have *no native way* to display national flags.

It is possible to render flags with pure CSS (see [Phoca CSS Flags](http://www.phoca.cz/cssflags/) library).  But I do not recommend using it for practical purposes.

*Just use images for national flags.*

Reasons:

- CSS was never meant to render flags, it's just a wrong tool for that.
- Complexity and size of CSS — a PNG image may turn out smaller than a CSS,
- Complexity of processing of this CSS — may degrade browser performance,
- Search engines *may* be able to recognize images as national flags, but are unlikely to recognize fancy-styled empty boxes as flags.

---

That said, *you don't have to use `<img>` elements in HTML to display flags*. Define `lang` attributes on content and use `:lang` selector to display images in front of and/or after paragraphs in specific languages.

An example (note that HTML markup only contains semantic `lang` attributes, and no flag images):

```css
p:lang(en):before,
p:lang(en):after
{
  content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ384.gif);
}

p:lang(nl):before,
p:lang(nl):after
{
  content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKGZe.gif);
}
```

```html
<p lang="en">This is an English text.</p>
<p lang="nl">Dit is een Nederlandse text.</p>
```